# the tableView has many different styles

Tags: tableview

When the tableView has different styles, what should I do？I got two solutions， 1.Creating several different cells，and their Identifier are also different
2.Linear layout，like android。
which solution is better

Answer (score 0):

I think first choice is better. You can set different cell id for each cell style. It is very easy to implement in storyboard.

Comment: This sounds like completely opinion based question and answer.